# MVC virtual magical mapping or "model binding"

Tags: asp.net-mvc

A MVC controller takes a few form items passed to it.
Let's say Name and Address.

In the [Post] controller
It receives a Person Object.

The MVC magical mapping takes place and the Person Object is filled.

1) What is the correct term for this magical mapping?

> MODEL BINDING

2) Why if my Person object has virtual object, it doesn't get magically filled up?

OK so here is some REAL code.

```
public class PackageItem
    {
        public int ProposalItemID { get; set; }
        public virutal PackageByContract { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
    public class EquipmentItem
    {
        public int ProposalItemID { get; set; }
        public virtual EquipmentByContract { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
    public class ProposalItem
    {
        public PackageItem PackageItem { get; set; }
        public EquipmentItem EquipmentItem { get; set; }
    }


EquipmentByContract
```

and

PackageByContract
objects both have

```
EquipmentByContractID
```

and

```
PackageByContractID 


<select name="PackageItem.PackageByContract.PackageByContractID"...>
<select name="PackageItem.EquipmentByContract.EquipmentByContractID"...>
```

Post the controller
Upon Debugging `PackageByContractID` and `EquipmentByContractID` are both `null`

Valued being sent are `int`

In my controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(ProposalItem Item)
 {...}
```

Upon hovering over the Item, both objects appear.
When I drill through it both values are null.

Comment: yeee haaa! Thanks Mr. Berkan

Comment: Explain what you mean better by part 2 (e.g. with example code)

Comment: @MartinSmith ok i posted the code thanks!

Comment: What values are you sending in the Post request? Which of those classes does your action take as argument?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov added some more code

Answer (score 0):

MVC needs some very specific inputs with very specific ids to be posted in order to work its Model Binding magic.

If the model is coming back null, you either don't have an input corresponding to each property of your model, or your ids are wrong.

Check out this [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) for some ideas of what it should look like.